# SQL Server Email Pastes Literal HTML

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am attempting to use `HTML` in my sql server send mail, but my email just shows what I type instead of formatting properly.  Can someone show me what needs to be altered in order for this to appear as `HTML`

```
declare @body1 varchar(4000)
set @body1 = '<html>
        <body style="background: #e3e3e3;">
        <center>
        <table style="width: 800px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="c:\2.png" alt="Image 2" /></br></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </center>
        </body>
        </html>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Mod',
    @from_address = 'modis@modisglobal.com',
    @recipients= 'rsmith@gmail.com',
    @subject= 'Test Email', 
    @body = @body1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx), you can see there's a `@body_format` option.

> [ @body_format= ] 'body_format' Is the format of the message body. The
>   parameter is of type varchar(20), with a default of NULL. When
>   specified, the headers of the outgoing message are set to indicate
>   that the message body has the specified format. The parameter may
>   contain one of the following values: TEXT HTML Defaults to TEXT.

Set it to `HTML`.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Mod',
    @from_address = 'modis@modisglobal.com',
    @recipients= 'rsmith@gmail.com',
    @subject= 'Test Email', 
    @body = @body1,
    @body_format = 'HTML'
```